# Не видит значение

Tags: php

в общем написал на php, там есть поле с именем `name`, мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку запроса, чтоб он находил в файле слово `123456` и заменял на то значение, которое вписали в поле. метод: `method="POST"` в файле к которому обращается кнопка запроса, прописал `$name=$_POST['name'];` Поиск и замену текста делаю так:

```
$filename = 'file.class';
$file = file_get_contents($filename);
$file = str_replace('123456', '$name', $file);
file_put_contents($filename, $file);
```

При открытии файла, вместо значения, которое написал в поле, вижу просто `$name`, а в случае `print $name` он отображает значение, которое я вписал. в чём ошибка??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Измените

```
str_replace('123456', '$name', $file); на str_replace('123456', $name, $file);
```

Comment: Покажите код полностью.